# Is it possible to submit Ad-hoc IPA to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, sign, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I've created and sent an Ad-Hoc signed IPA to my customer. I don't want them to be able to submit the application to the App Store, until I am paid. Are they able to re-sign the IPA, and upload it to App Store without me knowing?

Comment: No. They will not be able to. It has to done via your iTunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ad hoc application will be not accepted on the AppStore since is signed with an ad hoc provisioning profile. So if you send just the IPA I can't find an easy way to do that, but if you send the project or the archive made by Xcode they could resign and send to AppStore.